# String or binary data would be truncated. I got this error while inserting values in the password field

Tags: sql, asp.net, string, webforms

I have been working on sign up page using ASP.NET web forms ,,I had added a password and confirmed password. But only one field is define for both password and confirmed password in SSMS. But after debugging i got this error ,,, Kindly help me with this .. plz if any one  ??

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into SignUP " + "(FirstName,LastName,Email,Gender,Address,PhoneNumber,Password) values(@FirstName,@LastName,@Email,@Gender,@Address,@PhoneNumber,@Password)" , con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", Gender.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", PhoneNumber.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", pass.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Label1.Text = "Sign Up done ";
```

Comment: You can check the size of password field and increase the field of size like (ex. password nvarchar(500)).